# Finding linkedIn article on anomaly detection

Tags: time-series, linkedin-api, anomaly-detection

Last week I saw a LinkedIn article on anomaly detection. In that post, Tail movement of a running mice on rotating rod ( roller) is captured with CV and plotted as a time series. Then based on the tail movement time series , anomalities in that time series are detected where mice loose the balance in rotating rod.

I am trying to find this post in linkedIn but still didnt able get any clue. If you have seen this research article or have any clue please let me know. It will be great help. Appriciate you time and help.Thank You very much !